# Changing the series in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a chart on one of my sheets and I need to change a series in it in code. The problem is that I keep getting the error 1004 message. I've looked around and can't find a reason for it. Here's the code:

`Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Formula = "=G49:I" & dblResult & ")"`

Comment: You have a closing parenthesis, but not an opening one in your formula. However, I'm not sure that this will resolve your issue. Have you tried recording a macro to see how the system would manage this change?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you trying this?

```
Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Formula = _
"=SERIES(,," & "Charts!G49:I" & dblResult & ",1)"
```

Comment: +1 I was getting there myself... :-) @user2337549, I used this to find the proper format: `Debug.Print Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Formula`

Comment: THis should work. I find it easier to just assign the `SeriesCollection(1).Values`, `.XValues`, etc., though.  Never liked the "Series" formula :)  To each his own!

Comment: @DavidZemens - I'm with you on this one. Some things in Excel haven't changed since 1988... they are just carried around like bad baggage. While it's nice for backwards compatibility (although that is spotty at best, with most Office automation), it leads to ugliness like this. I'll get off my soap box now.

Comment: @user2337549 - when you find a useful answer like Sid's, it would be nice if you "accepted" it by clicking the little check mark. It marks it as "the right answer" for future visitors, and it gives him some "reputation" (although, in the VBA world at least, he's got plenty.... more than a number can express)

Comment: @DavidZemens: Yes, I also use `.Values` and `.XValues` and was thinking if I should post that as well but then decided against it. Why don't you post it since you suggested it? ;)

Comment: @SiddharthRout I've suggested it!

Answer (score 7):

An alternative that I prefer to manipulating the Series Formula is to just work with the individual properties of the `SeriesCollection`.

**Note** I'm writing this from memory/untested so let me know if there's any problems with it!

Inside the `With` block, you would need to determine the Ranges to use for the `Values`, `XValues`, `Name`, and `Order`, of course you can omit the parts that you don't need (e.g., I rarely need to manipulate the series `.Order`)

```
Dim cht as Chart
Dim srs as Series  '# Series variable'
Dim s as Long  '# Series iterator'
Dim ws as Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set cht = ws.ChartObjects(1).Chart '## Modify as needed.'

For each srs in cht.SeriesCollection
    With srs
        s = s+1
        .Values = ws.Range("Some_Range_For_Values")
        .XValues = ws.Range("Range_For_XValues")
        .Name = ws.Range("Range_For_SeriesName")
        .Order = s  
    End With
Next
```

Practically speaking, here is a pretty simple example. I often build or update a chart dynamically using an approach like this. Assuming that `XValues` are in column A, while series data is in columns B:F, you could do something like:

```
Dim rngData as Range '# A range containing all of the series values & xValues'
Dim s as Long
Dim cht as Chart
Dim srs as Series
Dim ws as Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set cht = ws.ChartObjects(1).Chart
Set rngData = Range("A2:F10")  

'## I like to remove existing series, and then add in the new data. '
For each srs in cht.SeriesCollection
    srs.Delete
Next

'## Iterate over our range and add series back in to the chart.'

For s = 2 to rngData.Columns.Count
    Set srs = cht.NewSeries
    With srs
        .XValues = rngData.Columns(1).Address
        .Values = rngData.Columns(s).Address
        'Name = rngData.Cells(1,s).Offset(-1,0).Value
        'Order = s-1  
    End With
Next
```

Comment: For my Excel version (O365, Feb. '19), I had to do `Set srs = cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries`. Otherwise, this was very helpful; much appreciated!